# Help with understanding a stipulation in pumping lemma

Tags: automata, pumping-lemma

I have an example problem we are doing where we have xy. The special string I picked for the specific question was 0^p 1 1 0^p. My question is that when we "pump" Y, only part of y gets pumped so that the string results in 0^p+k 1 | 1 0^p. Why do we only pump the first half of Y if the whole special string is equal to Y? I tried to ask for help but the only explanation I got was because of the stipulation |xy| <= p

Comment: Does your definition of pumping lemma not do a tripartite division of the string into $xyz$, only $xy$?

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is the pumping length of your language $L$, the pumping lemma guarantees that $w = 0^p 1 1 0^p$ can be decomposed as $xyz$ with $|xy| \le p$, $|y| \ge 1$, and $xy^iz \in L$ for all integers $i \ge 0$.

Since $|xy| \le p$ and the first $p$ symbols of $w$ are $0$s, it must be that both $x$ and $y$ contain only $0$s. Therefore any decomposition of $w$ must be of the form $x=0^h$, $y=0^k$, $z = 0^{p-h-k} 1 1 0^p$, for some choice of $k$ and $h$ that satisfies $k + h \le p$ and $k \ge 1$.

From what you write it seems that you choose to repeat $y$ once, which corresponds to picking $i=2$. The resulting word is:
$$x y^2 z = \underbrace{0^h}_x \; \underbrace{0^{2k}}_{y^2} \;\underbrace{0^{p-h-k} 1 1 0^p}_z = 0^{p+k} 1 1 0^p.$$

Answer (score 0):

Go back to how the pumping lemma is created: If L is regular then there is a state machine recognising L with p states. If you process the first n characters of a string, you must visit at least one state twice. If you moved from state X to state X while processing k >= 1 characters, then leaving these characters out, or duplicating them, or repeating them a billion times would all go to the same state X. And if you started by processing a string in L, then processing the missing characters will end in an accepting state.

And if you write that down formally you have the pumping lemma.